# Magento only displaying CSS updates on secure URL

Tags: html, css, security, magento, styling

I'm having a rough time with Magento. I spent a good deal of time going through the user guide on the Responsive theme, setting up Compass and editing SCSS files and whatnot, but was having the hardest time getting the changes to actually appear on the frontend.

I refreshed/flushed the cache, deleted contents of var/session and var/cache folders, I made sure the site was picking up the correct .css file under 'page source' in chrome.

It seemed like I could get the changes to apply if I changed 'merge css files' to yes, but even when the changes displayed if I made updates they wouldn't be pushed to the front end!

I changed the base URLs, however, and noticed that the secure URL for our site will load the correct .css and actually display the changes, while the unsecured URL says its loading the same .css file but NOT showing the changes.

I'm sure this is simple, but I'm going insane trying to figure out exactly what the problem is.  Please let me know if you need more specifics from me!

Thanks a bunch,
Jesse

Comment: do you have full page caching on your magento store?  Also are you using Apache or Nginx?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I believe Apache through cPanel, and I don't believe we have full page caching, seems like thats only available through the enterprise edition or extensions.

Comment: Also I realized upon further inspection that the two css files being loaded are the same file, just with different edits that I made over a period of time.  The secure URL is just displaying the more recent configuration of the file...What's weird though is that if I make edits and re-compile and upload them to the server, clear all caches, and hard refresh, the changes aren't applying to the secure URL either.  It's like they are both not loading the proper file, and instead are loading the file from different points in its revision history. Which I guess would make sense if its caching

Comment: sounds like you have browser caching configured on the server - typically in your .htaccess file.  confirm by entering the full url of your stylesheet here;

http://www.webconfs.com/http-header-check.php

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200 OK => 
Server => Sucuri/Cloudproxy
Date => Sun, 18 Oct 2015 13:45:34 GMT
Content-Type => text/css
Content-Length => 229610
Connection => close
Vary => Accept-Encoding
Last-Modified => Fri, 16 Oct 2015 20:01:19 GMT
Cache-Control => max-age=315360000
Expires => Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT
X-XSS-Protection => 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options => SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options => nosniff
Accept-Ranges => bytes

Comment: bingo: Expires => Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55.  Take a look in your .htaccesss file (root directory of magento) and modify the expires config

Comment: I'm not seeing that date anywhere in our .htaccess file...the only place I'm finding the word 'expires' is:<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

Comment: header details are usually configured on the server that serves the page. without knowing your full setup its difficult to be sure though

Comment: Hey I figured it out, we actually did have full page caching enabled through the outside security software! Thanks so much for the help!